# How to change default picture application to my own picture?

Tags: android, icons, screen

When I run my application, it's automatically create a droid-bot picture on surface of application. So, I want to change a picture, what should I do?

Comment: First of all you should accept some answers on your other questions and then you should try to use the search function before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) create a PNG image (say icon.png) and save it in the folder:

```
res/drawable
```

(2) Then, in AndroidManifest.xml of your application add the icon tag in your application:

```
android:icon=”@drawable/icon”
```

e.g.

```
<application android:name ="yourAppMgr" android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                //... >
```

Comment: You should try to generalize your answer a bit. Just by putting it into the `drawable-hdpi` folder the problem won't be solved and also it is not 48x48px for high density. It would be 72x72px.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't change the icon of installed application with some completely custom one, but you can add application shortcut with custom image to the home screen from your application.