# Use my own default picture on roboter Peppers tablet

Tags: pepper

I am using Aldebaran-Softbanks Pepper robot. Per default it's tablet shows an animtion with colored dots.

I want to change that to my own png-picture.

I still have a project/package with a "Show Image" behaviour which displays my picture without problems. I installed this package to the robot and set the autostart flag.

While starting Pepper the picture is shown for some seconds and then it disapears because of the deffault-start-pepper-behaviour which shows a softbank logo, an animated cloud of colored dots and fancy things like that.

My current workaround is to add a "Wait" box between the start-event and the "ShowImage" box. The wait is 22 seconds.

There is a similar [looking question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4802829/4865723) but the topic doesn't really fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create empty application. Make a folder named 'html' and place your image inside it.
2. Add [this setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495773/pepper-robot-default-image/43518227#43518227) to your robots database either [here](https://cloud.aldebaran-robotics.com/prefs/#/preferencesUser) or via [SSH](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/core/alpreferencemanager.html?highlight=database)
3. Restart the robot